# Scalding: Cannot reduce with partial function

Tags: scala, types, reduce, scalding

I am using scalding to do a simple word count type of things. I get an error when using partial function to expand on the tuple. The exact error message is:

```
Error:(15, 14) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, ?) => ?
      .reduce{ case ((t1, v1), (t2, v2)) =>
             ^
```

Adding types to the tuple does not help as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
TypedPipe.from(PackedAvroSource[TrackPlay](args("input")))
  .map({ t => (t.getTrackId.toString, 1) })
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .reduce{ case ((t1, v1), (t2, v2)) =>
      (t1, v1 + v2)
  }
  .values
  .write(TypedTsv[(CharSequence, Int)](args("output")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the type as the compiler cannot infer the correct type:

```
.reduce[(String, Int)] { case ((t1, v1), (t2, v2)) => (t1, v1 + v2) }
```

The type is specified as `[U >: Tuple2[String, Int]]` so the compiler infers `Tuple2[Any, Any]` and is therefore not able to compute the expected result type `Tuple2[String, Int]`.

More on this in section 8.5: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf

---

As a side note, a simpler implementation for your overall logic is:

```
TypedPipe.from(PackedAvroSource[TrackPlay](args("input")))
  .map(t => (t.getTrackId.toString, 1))
  .group
  .sum
  .toTypedPipe
  .write(TypedTsv[(CharSequence, Int)](args("output")))
```

Comment: You're not answering why my way does not work. You should be able to use case statements to expand on tuple. There are many ways to do this and I just want to know why reduce with case statement does not work. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why it worked without using the case statement. Very confusing.